# partitioning 10 into odd parts using generating function.

Tags: combinatorics

Use generating functions to find the number of ways to partition 10 into odd parts.

I am not really sure how to go about doing this. i know it is a product series, but i am not sure how to find the partitions

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The ordinary generating function for odd partitions is
$$
A(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}.
$$
Why?  If $a_n$ is the number of ways that you can partition $n$ in to a single odd number, then $a_n=1$ if $n$ is odd (you can write the number as itself) and $a_n=0$ if $n$ is even; thus
$$
A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k+1}=x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k}=x\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2},\qquad\lvert x\rvert<1.
$$
Now, what does the coefficient by $x^n$ in $A(x)\cdot A(x)$ tell you?  How about in $(A(x))^3$?  Or for $(A(x))^k$ in general?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it correctly Nicholas is suggesting we sum the series $A+A^2+A^3+\dots$ you may verify that this gives a closed-form expression leading to:
$$
P^{odd}(n) = \sum_{0  \le j \le \frac{n-1}2} \binom{n-1-j}{j}
$$
which gives 55 odd partitions of 10